# Form to select an instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button

I want my app to let the user choose between a few addresses or create one. The address is to be stored inside the contract object (Contract.adresse_id).

The controller generating the page displaying the form generate a @user variable.
The goal is to either pass the id of an existing address to the next controller, or to pass the params of a new adress (classic nested). This page only goal is to set the adress, no other fields of Contract should be modified.

The model Contract has a address_id field. I want a radio button allowing to choose between :

- `@user.address # it is an address id`
- `@user.secondary_adress # address id too`
- and an empty form allowing to create your own address.(classic  nested)

i guess it should look like :

```
<%= form_for contract do |f|%>        
<% f.label :address%>   
<% end%>
```

But then i do not know what to do. How can i do a form allowing to chose between 3 addresses where 2 already exists and the third is to be created ?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your third radio option an 'id' of 0 or -1.  Then in the next controller when you look up the Address, you instead make a new Address if the id is your fake non-id.  You could probably use the same view in either case on that next controller by setting the url of that form based on whether the Address is new. eg:

```
- if @address.new_record?
  - form_url = [create path]
- else
  - form_url = [update path]
...
 = form_for(@address, :url => form_url) do |f|
```

(That's in haml instead of erb, obviously.  I highly recommend making the switch)

Answer (score 0):

My problem is in 2 part :

1) choose an existing address to put it in contrat
2) add the possibility to create a new address instead of the existing ones in the same page

For 1) i did this :

```
<%= form_for @contract ,:action => "confirm" do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.radio_button 'address',@user.address.id, :checked => true %>
  <%= render @user.address %>
  </div>

  <div><%= f.radio_button 'address',@user.address_secondary.id, :checked => true %>
  <%= render @user.address %>
  </div>
  <%= f.

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

It simply submit the id of the chosen existing address

2) Instead of making a complicated single form allowing to chose between the two, i did a second form with a nested new address. It imply i create a new address in the previous controller, but if i do not use it, it's not a problem.

In the end my page have two different form submitting different data but it is way easier to do.